# I'm trying to draw a custom shape in flutter, but unfortunately the shape doesn't appear, I just see the white container

Tags: flutter, dart

this is the custom shape code

```
class SignInPageCustomShape extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    final Color myColor = Colors.black12;
    paint.color = myColor;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height * 0.9167);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width * 0.25,
      size.height * 0.875,
      size.width * 0.5,
      size.height * 0.9167,
    );
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width * 0.75,
      size.height * 0.9584,
      size.width * 1.0,
      size.height * 0.9167,
    );
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

and this is my widget tree,I don't know what is wrong, I tried to put my container in different places, but the same result is gotten, stack overflow is asking me to explain more, but I haven't anything else to explain .

```
class Paint extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: SignInPageCustomShape(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are facing might be because you haven't defined a child in CustomPaint

I added an empty Container and run the code and got this results

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8wVP.png)

Naming your StatelessWidget `Paint` is not recommended also

```
class Paint extends StatelessWidget {
```

The following method accepts two parameters one of type Paint because you defined a custom widget with the same name it was passing the wrong parameter in my case

```
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Code I used to get the results attached in this response:
Paint Widget:

```
class PaintWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: SignInPageCustomShape(),
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

SignInPageCustomShape Widget:

```
class SignInPageCustomShape extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();

    final Color myColor = Colors.black12;
    paint.color = myColor;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height * 0.9167);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width * 0.25,
      size.height * 0.875,
      size.width * 0.5,
      size.height * 0.9167,
    );

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width * 0.75,
      size.height * 0.9584,
      size.width * 1.0,
      size.height * 0.9167,
    );

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```